# How to fix this issue that I'm getting while executing map-reduce java code in Eclipse in Windows 10?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I am trying to execute a Java Program to Count the words in the input file using mapreduce in hadoop. I am using windows 10 and eclipse IDE.
I am getting fileNotFoundException when the reducer starts executing. Mapper executes completely. Please help to resolve the issue. Stuck here for quite a while.

```
public class CountMax {
    public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,IntWritable> {
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,Context context) throws IOException,InterruptedException{
            String line = value.toString();
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
            while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                value.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
                context.write(value, new IntWritable(1));
            }
            System.out.println("In mapper");
        }
    }

    public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
        public int maxCount = 0;
        public String maxCountWord = "";

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,Context context) throws IOException,InterruptedException {
            int sum=0;
            for(IntWritable x: values)
                sum+=x.get();
            if(sum>maxCount){
                maxCountWord = key.toString();
                maxCount = sum;
                System.out.println(sum);
                System.out.println(key);
            }
            System.out.println(maxCountWord);
        }    
        public void setup(Context context)throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            System.out.println("in SETUP");
        }


        protected void cleanup(Context context)throws IOException,InterruptedException {
            context.write( new Text(maxCountWord), new IntWritable(maxCount) );

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
        job.setJarByClass(CountMax.class);
        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
        Path inp = new Path("C:/input.txt");
        Path out = new Path("C:/output");
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, inp);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, out);
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

This is what I'm getting in the console :

```
2019-10-07 00:07:39,461 INFO  mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:run(249)) - Finishing task: attempt_local2096667908_0001_m_000000_0
2019-10-07 00:07:39,461 INFO  mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:runTasks(456)) - map task executor complete.
2019-10-07 00:07:39,463 INFO  mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:runTasks(448)) - Waiting for reduce tasks
2019-10-07 00:07:39,463 INFO  mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:run(302)) - Starting task: attempt_local2096667908_0001_r_000000_0
2019-10-07 00:07:39,472 INFO  output.FileOutputCommitter (FileOutputCommitter.java:<init>(108)) - File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
2019-10-07 00:07:39,472 INFO  util.ProcfsBasedProcessTree (ProcfsBasedProcessTree.java:isAvailable(192)) - ProcfsBasedProcessTree currently is supported only on Linux.
2019-10-07 00:07:39,499 INFO  mapred.Task (Task.java:initialize(614)) -  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.WindowsBasedProcessTree@7734a2ef
2019-10-07 00:07:39,501 INFO  mapred.ReduceTask (ReduceTask.java:run(362)) - Using ShuffleConsumerPlugin: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle@18daa432
2019-10-07 00:07:39,509 INFO  reduce.MergeManagerImpl (MergeManagerImpl.java:<init>(205)) - MergerManager: memoryLimit=1314232704, maxSingleShuffleLimit=328558176, mergeThreshold=867393600, ioSortFactor=10, memToMemMergeOutputsThreshold=10
2019-10-07 00:07:39,510 INFO  reduce.EventFetcher (EventFetcher.java:run(61)) - attempt_local2096667908_0001_r_000000_0 Thread started: EventFetcher for fetching Map Completion Events
2019-10-07 00:07:39,528 INFO  mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:runTasks(456)) - reduce task executor complete.
2019-10-07 00:07:39,532 WARN  mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:run(560)) - job_local2096667908_0001
java.lang.Exception: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle$ShuffleError: error in shuffle in localfetcher#1
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:529)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle$ShuffleError: error in shuffle in localfetcher#1
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle.run(Shuffle.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:376)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$ReduceTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:319)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:/tmp/hadoop-SahilJ%20PC/mapred/local/localRunner/SahilJ%20PC/jobcache/job_local2096667908_0001/attempt_local2096667908_0001_m_000000_0/output/file.out.index
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.open(RawLocalFileSystem.java:200)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:768)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SecureIOUtils.openFSDataInputStream(SecureIOUtils.java:155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SpillRecord.<init>(SpillRecord.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SpillRecord.<init>(SpillRecord.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SpillRecord.<init>(SpillRecord.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.LocalFetcher.copyMapOutput(LocalFetcher.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.LocalFetcher.doCopy(LocalFetcher.java:102)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.LocalFetcher.run(LocalFetcher.java:85)
```

Comment: You should remove spaces in the path `C:/tmp/hadoop-SahilJ%20PC/` (create a different user account just named SahilJ)

Comment: @cricket_007 I tried it but now it's giving this error though all the paths are perfectly setup ERROR util.Shell (Shell.java:getWinUtilsPath(400)) - Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just making a new user account without any space in the name, with all the admin rights and doing the whole setup again in the new account worked and solved the issue.